# Ubuntu 18 - how to set up a static IP and DNS

Tags: networking, network-manager, interface, virtualbox-networking

I need to configure an Ubuntu 18 client with static IP and static private DNS IP. I changed the `etc/network/interfaces` file to:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
address 192.168.34.9
netmask 255.255.255.0

dns-nameservers 192.168.34.2
```

My DNS is `192.168.34.2`. I am using virtualbox and Ubuntu is installed in a virtual machine. I have two interface cards. One is NAT (and I disabled it) and the second is `Host-only` adapter which means internal.

I can ping the DNS but it can not resolve other server names. The other servers are pingable. The Ubuntu 18 seems not configured correctly to see the DNS. Can you help me please.

Comment: What other names are you trying to resolve? An example of a few that doesn’t work?

Comment: Whatch out because on Ubuntu 18 is enable by default netplan and not ifupdown